# I see clickbait ads

Tags: bug, status-completed

On this site, I can see low-quality clickbait ads pretty often. Here are some screenshots (they're in Greek, links intentionally not included):

[image: Clickbait ad.]

[image: Clickbait ad.]

[image: Clickbait ad.]

I'm pretty sure this isn't supposed to happen here, and it's really degrading the site's quality, so I'd appreciate it if this could be fixed. I haven't seen it on any other community so far, that's why I'm posting it here and not on mother meta. All three examples' links start with this:

```
https://stackoverflow-d.openx.net/w/1.0/rc?ts=2DAABBgABAAECAAIBAAsAAgAAA
```

Comment: I'd bet money you've got a nasty on your computer somewhere - either a virus or (more likely) a rogue browser extension.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I'm 100% sure that's not at all true. I've got a constantly updating Kaspersky Antivirus 2019 and each and every extension is checked. Also, I think that the URL prefix ensures that too.

Comment: I can confirm this, visiting from a pristine temporary Chromium profile. I get clickbait scam/spam advertisements in German, mixed with the regular ones, all from the same openx domain.

Comment: @ByteCommander Same URL prefix? Asking so that the responsible team might be able to pinpoint it to a single offender that slipped through the cracks.

Comment: Yup, exactly the same URL pattern.

Comment: Further investigation suggests that this is a problem on all sites across the network (at least the smaller sites which don't serve their own community ads or get otherwise topical/filtered ads only).

Comment: @ByteCommander Huh, not for me... and I've whitelisted every SE site from my ad blocker.

Comment: @EKons I am forwarding this to the appropriate team. Thank you for posting the images and URL!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These ads have been reported and the possible funnel closed. OpenX was contacted and they have addressed the issue. Please let me know if you see them again.

Comment: The only thing I'm seeing now (and for a few hours already) is blank white areas where the ads used to be (my ad blocker has been set to whitelist Stack Exchange), and I refreshed a few times, so I'll say that, for now, the issue has been solved. Thanks for your assistance!